# Windows Server 2008 Login Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

When I try to login I am getting following error.

> There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request

Server has installed ADS. I Checked Active Directory Domain Controller Service and DNS Server Service not running. And Also Unable to start them manually.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Those services being stopped would be the cause of your login problems. You need to troubleshoot and find out why they're not running and why you can't start them. Start by looking in the Event logs, if you can access them.

Comment: I am able to login in server without domain user. When I Try to start DNS Services it start and stop immediately. And Even viewer log that DNS service can not start it depends on Active Directory Domain Controller. When I Try To Active Directory Domain Controller it also does not start unable to get its log.